# Looking for scheduling software that can handle resources

Tags: scheduling

We are looking for software with which we can schedule recurring work visits, assign crews, and track resources so that a guy on crew A cannot be assigned to crew B at the same time.

It should have a great drag-n-drop calendar view and allow recurring events that can be edited individually or as a group - a la Outlook.

The less other stuff, the better. We don't want QuickBooks integrations, we don't want client contact, we don't want field techs to be able to communicate with the system. The ideal solutions would be for inside - office use only.

The gold standard would have a feature where you could create a job to be put into "limbo" so that it could be dragged to a scheduling spot at a later date. It would also have a pool of resources that could be assigned (drag/drop) to each job.

Our office is Windows 7, and we'd prefer to keep everything locally, though browser/cloud based solution would be welcome at this point. It does NOT need to be free, but it should also not be priced in such a way that every person you want to schedule is considered a user, and therefore subject to higher prices based on number of users - I add this because several potential solutions require that all 20 of the people being scheduled are users - requiring fees many times that of what we really need.

I doubt I'll find exactly what we're looking for, but I'm hoping you guys and gals can make some suggestions.

Comment: By "resources" do you mean employees, or computer files?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - well we are a landscape design/build company. In our case "resources" are employees and heavy equipment that need to be scheduled.

Comment: How many users do you have, and what kind of infrastructure do you have?  For example, do you have a Windows domain and one or more IT people already?  Do you run your own Exchange Server?

Comment: @DanWhaley We are a small landscape company with 4 or so scheduling users. The office has no IT people on staff  - just an on-call consultant. We are on Windows and we outsource our exchange services.

Comment: Since you already outsource your Exchange services and use Outlook, why not create calendars for your field guys and share their calendars with the office people?  From a technical and usability standpoint, that's your best bet.

Comment: @DanWhaley The field guys do not have email or computer access. Communication with them is limited to occasional calls to crew chiefs. We now also want to generate work orders from the calendar...

Comment: The field guys don't have to be able to access the calendars that represent them.  You just have to have calendars to represent them in Exchange, so you can easily book them in Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

There are various software available on the internet purposely made for scheduling of resources. One which we are using and I thought it should suit your requirements is eResource Scheduler made by Enbraun.
It is very easy to use resource management & scheduling software that's why we are using it since 2 years.

You can find about it on their website: [www.eresourcescheduler.com](https://www.eresourcescheduler.com)